# Unable to export graph into Excel using Python xlsxwriter

Tags: python, excel, pandas, graph, xlsxwriter

I wanted to export two graphs (one is a column bar chart and the second is line chart).
The axes and legend are placed properly but the data is not populating in the graph

### Input Data Format

```
Date        Org     Vol     VolCum  OrgCum
2020-03-01  36.447  37.2    37.2    36.447
2020-03-02  38.742  39.6    76.8    75.189
2020-03-03  67.17   69.1    145.9   142.359
2020-03-04  39.875  40.9    186.8   182.234
2020-03-05  69.4    71.1    257.9   251.634
2020-03-06  39.488  40.3    298.2   291.122
2020-03-07  69.447  67.3    365.5   360.569
2020-03-08  78.55   81.9    447.4   439.119
```

It contains data of two columns and cumulative data for these columns. There are multiple excel worksheets in a similar way in the input file

### My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter 
df = pd.ExcelFile('dataset.xlsx')
sheets = df.sheet_names
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('dataset_with_graphs.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
for sheet in sheets:
  dataset  = pd.read_excel(df,sheet)
  worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet() 
  data = [ 
        [int(i) for i in df1['Date'].values]
        [int(i) for i in df1['Org'].values],
        [int(i) for i in df1['Vol'].values],
        [int(i) for i in df1['VolCum'].values],
        [int(i) for i in df1['OrgCum'].values]
    ] 
  worksheet.write_column('A2', data[0]) 
  worksheet.write_column('B2', data[1]) 
  worksheet.write_column('C2', data[2]) 
  worksheet.write_column('D2', data[3]) 
  worksheet.write_column('E2', data[4]) 
  chart1 = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'column'}) 
  chart1.add_series({ 
        'name':  '= '+i+' !$B$1', 
        'categories': '= '+i+' !$A$2:$A$23', 
        'values':    '= '+i+' !$B$2:$B$23', 
    }) 
  chart1.add_series({ 
        'name':  '= '+i+' !$C$1', 
        'categories': '= '+i+' !$A$2:$A$23', 
        'values':    '= '+i+' !$C$2:$C$23', 
    }) 
   chart1.set_title ({'name': 'Results of data analysis'
   chart1.set_x_axis({'name': 'Date'})
   chart1.set_y_axis({'name': 'Volume'})chart1.set_style(11) 
   worksheet.insert_chart('G3', chart1) 


workbook.close()
```

### Expected Output

Same Data and create a bar chart for Org and Vol.
Create a line chart for VolCum and OrgCum for all the sheets present in the excel file